# constructing name of php variable

Tags: php

```
$service3_step1_person = ‘999’;    
echo $service3_step1_person;    //999
```

and then...

```
$service = "service3";    
echo "$".$service."_step1_person;  //$service3_step1_person
```

it doesn't give me **999**, just give me a string of `$service3_step1_person`.

How can I make the string become a new variable name? Thanks!

Comment: Although it can be done (see people's answers), it's akin to an `eval()` and not really good practice. Find other ways to store and access the value. e.g. `$service[3]["step"]["person"]`

Comment: It's called Variable variables, see http://docs.php.net/language.variables.variable . But it's usually easier done/more flexible with arrays. In your case maybe something like $services[3]['steps'][1]['person'].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
echo ${$service."_step1_person"};
```

Answer (score 2):

Variable variable:

```
$service3_step1_person = ‘999’;
$service = "service3";
$variableName = "{$service}_step1_person";  
echo $$variableName; // 999
```

Comment: replace $$variable with $$variableName . . this will give the exact output :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $service = "service3";
 $temp = "_step1_person";
 echo ${$service.$temp};
```